# App store approval with modified UISegmentedControl

Tags: ios, user-interface, uisegmentedcontrol, appstore-approval

I have modified a UISegmentedControl so that it is vertical instead of horizontal- it looks like this:

[image]

Will using it this way cause my app to get rejected by Apple? If yes, what control would you suggest using instead? Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As long as you are not using private APIs to do this I would say you are fine. Apple strongly suggests following the [Human Interface Guideline](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/Introduction/Introduction.html) but there are modified controls like this all over the AppStore. I highly doubt you'd get rejected for your custom design.