# Vertical SegmentController

Tags: iphone, ios, uisegmentedcontrol, uifont

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can I show an UISegmentedControl object in vertical?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3490358/can-i-show-an-uisegmentedcontrol-object-in-vertical)

How to make a UIsegmentController vertical ,I tried using,

```
segmentedControl.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI / 2.0);
```

but its make the segment control fonts to vertical.Can any one help me to code for vertical segmentcontrolbar?

Comment: BTW, there's no need to write `M_PI / 2.0`, there's already a `M_PI_2` constant defined (and `M_PI_4`, for what it's worth).

Comment: see some links in my answer with some desc... :)

Answer (score 0):

use this,

```
NSArray *arr = [segmentedControl subviews];
    for (int i = 0; i < [arr count]; i++) {
    UIView *v = (UIView*) [arr objectAtIndex:i];
    NSArray *subarr = [v subviews];
        for (int j = 0; j < [subarr count]; j++) {
            if ([[subarr objectAtIndex:j] isKindOfClass:[UILabel class]]) {
                UILabel *l = (UILabel*) [subarr objectAtIndex:j];
                l.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(- M_PI / 2.0);
            }
        }
    }
```

see [Can I show an UISegmentedControl object in vertical?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3490358/can-i-show-an-uisegmentedcontrol-object-in-vertical)

Comment: i want to make like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9168840/app-store-approval-with-modified-uisegmentedcontrol

Answer (score -1):

Try this bellow code with some change...

First define Radians on top of the .m file like bellow..

```
#define degreesToRadians(x) (M_PI * x / 180.0)
```

and after in `viewDidLoad:` or `viewWillAppear:` , try bellow code...

```
yoursegControl.transform = 
                CGAffineTransformRotate(segControl.transform, degreesToRadians(90));
```

**Try Dropdawn List,this is give the output like your Requirement **

hey, if you use Dropdawn list insted of this seg control then its also useful to your requirement, see...

http://code.google.com/p/dropdowndemo/downloads/list

:)

Comment: subview.subviews shows error..propert not found

Comment: i just want to make the segment control as like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9168840/app-store-approval-with-modified-uisegmentedcontrol

Comment: hey if insted of segment control you use dropdawn box then its ok??