# segment control position

Tags: iphone, ios, uisegmentedcontrol

The segment control is cant able to relocate the position in vertical.It shows like in the image .Can any one help me to positioning the segment control.

```
  int offset = BAR_OFFSET + 40 * bars.count;
  for (int i = bars.count; i < guessRows; i++)
  {
   UISegmentedControl *bar = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:
     [NSArray arrayWithObjects:@"", @"", @"", nil]];
   bar.segmentedControlStyle = UISegmentedControlStyleBar;
   bar.transform = CGAffineTransformMakeRotation(M_PI_2);
   bar.momentary = YES;
   [bar addTarget:self action:@selector(submitGuess:)
     forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
   CGRect frame = bar.frame;
   frame.origin.y = offset; // position it below the last bar
   frame.origin.x = 20; // give it some padding on the left
   [self.view addSubview:bar]; // add the bar to the main view
   [bars addObject:bar];
   [bar release]; 

 }
```

[image]

Comment: Please give the code leading to this situation.

Comment: @Vladimir question added with code.pls help me to solve

Comment: how you need to place the segment Controller ? i mean horizontal or vertical ? @iosdev

Comment: No i want to change the position of segment controler. @VenkatManohar

Comment: once try this bar.frame = CGRectMake(20, 20, 21, 200); @iosdev

Comment: @iosdev: could you please let me the actual position of your segmentController ?

Comment: @VenkatManohar i updated the code .Please check

Comment: now problem with making the segment control text ..i did the code from this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3490358/can-i-show-an-uisegmentedcontrol-object-in-vertical... its not working..i added the segement controll titles as like this                   `if ([[regions valueForKey:region] boolValue])
         {
             [bar setTitle:[name convertToDisplayName]
         forSegmentAtIndex:segmentIndex] ;
             
             ++segmentIndex;
         }` how should i proceed for rotating the segement control text.please help me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can create segment control programmatic and set frame to maintain your segment control position and add segmentcontrol to your view Controller  like this :-

```
 UISegmentedControl *segmentedControl = [[UISegmentedControl alloc] initWithItems:itemArray];
 segmentedControl.frame = CGRectMake(35, 200, 250, 50);
 segmentedControl.segmentedControlStyle = UISegmentedControlStylePlain;
 segmentedControl.selectedSegmentIndex = 1;

 [self.view addSubview:segmentedControl];
```

Comment: now problem with making the segment control text ..i did the code from this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3490358/can-i-show-an-uisegmentedcontrol-object-in-vertical... its not working..i added the segement controll titles as like this                   `if ([[regions valueForKey:region] boolValue])
         {
             [bar setTitle:[name convertToDisplayName]
         forSegmentAtIndex:segmentIndex] ;
             
             ++segmentIndex;
         }` how should i proceed for rotating the segement control text.please help me

Comment: have you trying like this 
 

[segmentedControl setTitle:<yourstring> forSegmentAtIndex:0];

Comment: then how can i rotate the text in uisegment view controller .

Comment: actually i did't get you clearly frnd.. :(
Please refure this http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UISegmentedControl_Class/Reference/UISegmentedControl.html

Comment: i tried to make vertical segment control like this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9168840/app-store-approval-with-modified-uisegmentedcontrol ,now segment control coming vertically,But i want font in horizontal.Now the font coming in vertical.Can yu please solve

Answer (score 1):

The problem comes from your `offset` var. At line :

```
frame.origin.y = offset; // position it below the last bar
```

Change its value (increase it to lower the position of the view) and try to find the correct value that displays your control correctly.

Comment: Yes ..problem with the offset oly @rdurand